# Custom Heroes - Charmy pile order reversal

Tags: custom-heroes

Charmy is a special ability in which reverses the numerical order of play. My question is about when the ability actually takes effect. Here's the rule text:

> After a player activates this special ability, the direction of the pile changes. If the values were ascending, they start descending, and vice versa. This effect lasts for the rest of the round. For example, after a Charmy is  played, to beat a pair of 4s, you would need to play a pairs of 4s or lower.

What I need clarification about revolves around the words `After`in the first sentence and `after` in the third sentence.

Does that mean that Charmy is played in

- normal order and the reversal occurs after that play, or
- immediate reversal on the play that Charmy is activated?

Examples of each

```
two 5s
two 7s
two 8s with Charmy activation
two 3s
```

Or

```
two 5s
two 7s
two 4s with Charmy activation
two 3s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal order and the reversal occurs after that play.

I'm not sure where the confusion lies because the description literally says the effect starts "after a Charmy is played". In fact, it mentions the reversal only happens after you play the card and activate the ability not once, but twice. Until you activate the ability by playing the card, you still need to play a card of equal of greater value.

Comment: The question arose because another player disputed the interpretation and I said that I would ask at this site. I agree with you, but I believe that it's worth asking the question so that a consensus interpretation is documented.

Comment: Step 1 - play the card. Step 2 - decide if you want to use the ability or gain one [resource... can't recall the name offhand]. The requirements to legally place a card are in effect for Step 1, even if you can't/won't use the ability.

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0, That's not correct. If that were true, Ascended Form wouldn't work. You decide whether you want to activate the card you will play, then you play it activated (for its effect), or you play it unactivated for a Power Token. But yes, only *after* this does Charmy's effect come into play.